# @MustOverride annotation?

Tags: java, interface, annotations, abstract-class, overriding

In .NET, one can specify a "mustoverride" attribute to a method in a particular superclass to ensure that subclasses override that particular method. 
I was wondering whether anybody has a custom java annotation that could achieve the same effect. Essentially what i want is to push for subclasses to override a method in a superclass that itself has some logic that must be run-through. I dont want to use abstract methods or interfaces, because i want some common functionality to be run in the super method, but more-or-less produce a compiler warning/error denoting that derivative classes *should* override a given method.

Comment: If you override a method in Java the method in the super-class will no longer be called, unless with an explicit "super.". So, I don't think your idea (force execution of a common superclass method) would work, even if such a attribute would exist.

Answer (score 22):

I don't quite see why you would not want to use abstract modifier -- this is intended for forcing implementation by sub-class, and only need to be used for some methods, not all. Or maybe you are thinking of C++ style "pure abstract" classes?

But one other thing that many Java developers are not aware of is that it is also possible to override non-abstract methods and declare them abstract; like:

```
public abstract String toString(); // force re-definition
```

so that even though `java.lang.Object` already defines an implementation, you can force sub-classes to define it again.

Comment: Make the method abstract. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: There are many times one may want to have base-logic in the super-method but have a reminder for future devs that without extending this logic and calling super(), the child can't expect normal behaviour as per business needs.

Comment: As an example of this-  most of the time we use BaseClass as is.  BaseClass has a copy function that returns a deep copy.  Calling ChildClass.copy() should return a new instance of the ChildClass, not the base class.  I would like to enforce the override at compile time to avoid subtle bugs in production where 1 or two fields aren't copied and return 0.

Answer (score 13):

Ignoring abstract methods, there is no such facility in Java. Perhaps its possible to create a compile-time annotation to force that behaviour (and I'm not convinced it is) but that's it.

The real kicker is "override a method in a superclass that itself has some logic that must be run through". If you override a method, the superclass's method won't be called unless you explicitly call it.

In these sort of situations I've tended to do something like:

```
abstract public class Worker implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public final void run() {
    beforeWork();
    doWork();
    afterWork();
  }

  protected void beforeWork() { }
  protected void afterWork() { }
  abstract protected void doWork();
}
```

to force a particular logic structure over an interface's method. You could use this, for example, to count invocations without having to worry about whether the user calls `super.run()`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

... and if declaring a base class `abstract` is not an option you can always throw an UnsupportedOperationException

```
class BaseClass {
    void mustOverride() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Must implement");
    }
}
```

But this is not a compile-time check of course...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure which attribute you're thinking about in .NET.

In VB you can apply the `MustOverride` *modifier* to a method, but that's just the equivalent to making the method abstract in Java. You don't need an attribute/annotation, as the concept is built into the languages. It's more than just applying metadata - there's also the crucial difference that an abstract method doesn't include any implementation itself.

If you *do* think there's such an attribute, please could you say which one you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Android has a new annotation out as announced in the Google I/O 2015:
@callSuper

More details here: 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

Comment: +1 for Usefulness, but doesn't answer the question. We need an annotation that warns the sub-class saying 'You must override this method'

Answer (score 1):

If you need some default behaviour, but for some reason it should not be used by specializations, like a implementation of a logic in a non abstract Adapter class just for easy of prototyping but which should not be used in production for instance, you could encapsulate that logic and log a warning that it is being used, without actually having to run it.

The base class constructor could check if the variable holding the logic points to the default one. (writing in very abstract terms as I think it should work on any language)

It would be something like this (uncompiled, untested and incomplete) Java (up to 7) example:

```
public interface SomeLogic {
 void execute();
}

public class BaseClass {

  //...private stuff and the logging framework of your preference...

  private static final SomeLogic MUST_OVERRIDE = new SomeLogic() {
    public void execute() {
      //do some default naive stuff
    }
  };

  protected SomeLogic getLogic() { return MUST_OVERRIDE; }

  //the method that probably would be marked as MustOverride if the option existed in the language, maybe with another name as this exists in VB but with the same objective as the abstract keyword in Java
  public void executeLogic() {
    getLogic().execute();
  }

  public BaseClass() {
    if (getLogic() == MUST_OVERRIDE) {
      log.warn("Using default logic for the important SomeLogic.execute method, but it is not intended for production. Please override the getLogic to return a proper implementation ASAP");
    }
  }

}

public GoodSpecialization extends BaseClass {

  public SomeLogic getLogic() {
    //returns a proper implementation to do whatever was specified for the execute method
  }

  //do some other specialized stuff...
}

public BadSpecialization extends BaseClass {

  //do lots of specialized stuff but doesn't override getLogic...
}
```

Some things could be different depending on the requirements, and clearly simpler, especially for languages with lambda expressions, but the basic idea would be the same.

Without the thing built in, there is always some way to emulate it, in this example you would get a runtime warning in a log file with a home-made-pattern-like-solution, that only your needs should point if it is enough or a more hardcore bytecode manipulation, ide plugin development or whatever wizardry is needed.

Answer (score -1):

I've been thinking about this.

While I don't know of any way to require it with a compile error, you might try writing a custom PMD rule to raise a red-flag if your forgot to override.

There are already loads of PMD rules that do things like reminding you to implement HhashCode if you choose to override equals. Perhaps something could be done like that.

I've never done this before, so I'm not the one to write a tutorial, but a good place to start would be this link http://techtraits.com/programming/2011/11/05/custom-pmd-rules-using-xpath/ In this example, he basically creates a little warning if you decide to use a wildcard in an import package. Use it as a starting point to explore how PMD can analyze your source code, visit each member of a hierarchy, and identify where you forgot to implement a specific method.

Annotations are also a possibility, but you'd have to figure out your own way to implement the navigation through the class path. I believe PMD already handles this. Additionally, PMD has some really good integration with IDEs.
https://pmd.github.io/