# Java : How to force a given protected method to be overloaded by children classes?

Tags: java, overloading, parent-child

The father class is not and cannot be made abstract.
The method to overload is protected so interfaces cannot be used there.

Having these two restrictions in mind is it possible to do it?

Comment: Also, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742463/mustoverride-annotation

Comment: @Jeff raises a good point in a comment to my answer: why can `Father` not be abstract? Is it because you cannot modify it?

Comment: I can change Father, but I need to be able to instantiate it. The logic is the following. In the great scheme of things, child classes call two methods a() and b(). But the b() method cannot (well, it doesn't make sense to do it) be called by the father classes.

Comment: Also, @Jeff ~ I never really dwelled in SOF system ~ anywhere I can read about it?

Answer (score 8):

You can't force the method to be overridden - that's what abstract methods are for (which you've stated isn't an option).

One possibility is to make the method in the base class throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Then, the subclass must override it in order to prevent the error being thrown. That way, you can at least detect if the method has been overridden.

For example:

```
public class Father {
    public void method ( ) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( );
    }
}

public class Child1 extends Father {

}
public class Child2 extends Father {
    public void method ( ) {
        // Do something useful here...
    }
}
```

Calling `Child1.method()` will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, indicating that it hasn't overridden `Father`'s `method()`. Calling `Child2.method()` will not throw the exception, meaning that it *has* overridden `method()`.

Comment: I assume that if he can't make the method abstract, he can't modify the "Father" class at all.  Of course this could be a baseless assumption.

Comment: @Jeff: that's entirely possible. I'm just going with the information that's been given, which (at this point) doesn't rule out this approach.

Comment: Far from the solution I wanted, but this should be able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could throw an UnsupportedOperationException from the parent.  That won't help at compile time but will at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Since abstract is not an option you could have the method throw a `NotImplementedException`. This is a more explicit exception then `UnsuppotedOperationException`.
**Note:** This will not prevent the code from compiling and will only throw an exception at run time.

```
Public Clazz {
    public void methodToOverride(){
        Throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Some Examples implemntations:
[Apache](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException.html)
[Sun](http://srcrr.com/java/oracle/openjdk/6/reference/sun/reflect/generics/reflectiveObjects/NotImplementedException.html)
[sharkysoft.com](http://sharkysoft.com/software/java/lava3/core/javadocs/com/sharkysoft/util/NotImplementedException.html)

Comment: `NotImplementedException` is specific to those particular frameworks. The standard Java exception (i.e. part of the JDK) to be used for this purpose is `UnsupportedOperationException`. Using it instead means you don't need to add an extra third-party dependency just for this purpose.

Comment: @Mac You could implement your own `NotImplementedException` that extends `UnsupportedOperationException`, you don't have to use third party dependencies, those are just examples. The advantage of `NotImplementedException` is that it is more explicit about what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess. The use of `UnsupportedOperationException` in this way is pretty idiomatic, but you're right in that there's no harm being more specific. If you're already using one of those frameworks or can be bothered making your own `NotImplementedException`, then that's probably not a bad thing.